# php - if time between 5 to the hour and 15 minutes past

Tags: php

I have an option on a page I want to remove if the page is loaded between 5 to the hour and 15 minutes past the hour, without putting in 24 different times, is there an easier way to do this? thanks

```
if (($time > 'five to the hour') && ($time < 'quarter past the hour')){
 //do something
}
else {}
```

Comment: Show us sample times and expected results

Comment: `date("i")` will show you current minutes.

Comment: example time, between 11:55 and 12:15 (5 to the hour and 15 past the hour), but for every hour of the day. expected results? I want to be able to do something between these times and something different outside of these times. Unsure why it's being downvoted, didn't think I could put it any clearer and no constructive criticism doesn't help

Comment: thanks u_mulder, that's perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mktime()` to make timestamps.

```
$current_hour = date('H') - 1;
if($current_hour < 0) {
    $current_hour = 23;
}

$time_before = mktime($current_hour, 55, 0);
$time_after = mktime(date('H'), 16, 0);
if($time_before <= time() AND $time_after > time()) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
if (intval(date('i', time())) > 15 && intval(date('i', time())) < 55) {
    // any time from hour:16 to hour:54, inclusive
} else {
    // any time until hour:15 or from hour:55
}
```